# Share values between several transformations?

Tags: java, design-patterns, guava

Imagine I have the following List of values:

```
List<String> values = Lists.asList("a", "a", "b", "c");
```

Now I want to add an index to all values, so that one ends up with this as list:

```
a1 a2 b1 c1 // imagine numbers as subscript
```

I want to use a [`FluentIterable`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html) and its [`transform`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#transform%28com.google.common.base.Function%29) method for that, so something like this:

```
from(values).transform(addIndexFunction);
```

The problem with that is, that `addIndexFunction` needs to know, how often the index was already increased - think of `a2`, when adding the index to this `a`, the function needs to know, that there was alraedy an `a1`.

So, is there some kind of best practice for doing such a thing? My current idea is to create a Map with each letter as key, so:

```
Map<String,Integer> counters = new HashMap<>();
// the following should be generated automatically, but for the sake of this example it's done manually...
counters.put("a", 0);
counters.put("b", 0);
counters.put("c", 0);
```

and then modify my transform call:

```
from(values).transform(addIndexFunction(counters));
```

As Map is an object and passed by reference, I can now share the counter state between the transformations, right? Feedback, better ideas? Is there some built-in mechanism for such things in Guava?

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: I don't think your going to find anything pre-built for this. Your idea sounds good, though I would encapsulate the counter map within the Function itself, and only create keys for items actually in the list (aka, lazy load the counting map).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and the idea of lazy loading sounds nice, didn't think of that :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use a [Multiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) to replace the HashMap, and you're good to go, following @Perception's suggestion to encapsulate the Multiset in the Function itself and aggregating data as the function is applied.

Comment: nice idea with the multiset, so one doesn't have to check if the item exists or not when trying to find out the count :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `transform` here, or your iterable will have different values every time you iterate over it, and will generally behave very weirdly.  (It's also somewhat frowned upon to have state in a `Function`.)

Instead, do a proper `for` loop with a `Multiset` helper:

```
Multiset<String> counts = HashMultiset.create();
List<Subscript> result = Lists.newArrayList();
for (String value : values) {
  int count = counts.add(value, 1);
  result.add(new Subscript(value, count));
}
```